# Use user input as the condition for an if statement

Tags: java

I would like the user to be able to set conditions for future events to trigger.
Following is a basic example:

```
BufferedReader reader = BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
var condition = reader.readLine();
if(condition){
    System.out.println("Condition satisfied");
}
```

So ideally I would like the user to be able to enter any condition, for example, `3<4` or also more intricate things like `"test".contains("t")`. I am working with the assumption that the user input will always be a valid condition that would compile if I were to write it in the program directly.

The problem is that when I read input from the console it is read as a String, is there a way to transform the string into code and use it as the if condition? If possible I would like to avoid the approach of using regex and scanning for a limited type of conditions.

Comment: use [compiler api](https://javabeat.net/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/)

Comment: It would seem that compiler API only works if you give java files as inputs. It doesn't seem to me like there is a way to implement it like I'd like right?